# Using xammp on windows, rewriting /var/www/

Tags: php, linux, windows, include, xampp

I normally design my websites on my linux apache server and in these files I always use full paths when I'm calling the include() function.

for example a typical index page may look something like this.

```
<?php
include_once('/var/www/sites/sitea/constants.php');

echo "Hello, welcome to my homepage";
?>
```

The problem is now that I want to test this site on windows 8 with xammp I would have to change the include extension in every php file, which is a pain.

Is there anyway I can tell xammp to treat `/var/www/site` as if it was `C:\xammp\htdocs\sites`

Comment: If you have a good IDE you can use the Refactor Functions to replace a String in multiple files

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Rizier123 that would be a pain, windows uses backslash whilst linux uses forward slash

Comment: Use relative paths or define your root path in a single constant instead. PHP has no problem at all with forward slashes in Windows paths, plus it has an OS-aware `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant.

Answer (score -1):

With Sublime Text you can search & replace multiple files at once.

http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html